# Controls on my Vantage VS-696 guitar

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups

I have this Vantage VS-696 guitar for decades that I used to use as a "Silent guitar" and never plugged in any amp.

Today I'm plugging it into a DSM & Humboldt Simplifier and I fail to understand what is the exact use of its controls.

Anyone knowing this guitar ?

[image: guitar knobs]

As far as I understand it :

1. Pickup selector Neck/Both/Bridge
2. Neck pickup volume or master volume ?
3. Bridge pickup volume ?
4. Tone
5. Neck pickup split (Single vs. Double)
6. ???

I don't exclude technical issues with the guitar also that could explain its strange behaviour.

Its "strange" behaviours are:

- In the *Middle* pickup selection (so Both pickups), setting (2) to 0 leads to no sound, whatever the position of (3) is. But when (2) is raised to 1 or more, then there is sound (while in *Bridge* position, (2) has no effect)
- In the *Middle* pickup selection (so Both pickups), setting (3) to 0 leads to no sound, whatever the position of (2) is. But when (3) is raised to 1 or more, then there is sound.
- (6) has little effect in *Bridge* position or *Middle* position. Certainly as (5) has in *Neck* position.

### Some more pictures and drawings##

**Colour cables**

[image: Colour cables]

Remarks:

- It is not clear whether the white cable from knob 4 is connected to knob 3
- The green cable from the incoming cable 2 seems to be connected to nothing.

**Black cables** (I guess the neutral point)

[image]

**Pictures**

[image]
[image]

EDIT: (I'm confused) it is VS-696 and not a 635
EDIT: added some of the strange behaviours
EDIT: Added pictures and drawings

Comment: An easy way to determine *some* of the controls is tapping pups with a house key, or similar piece of metal. That will give a clue as to which pups are controlled by which pots, and to an extent tone controls. Listening via a pair of cans makes the job easier.

Comment: Are there any identifying details on the guitar? The most common VS-635 is a completely different guitar. Knowing the actual model might help finding out what the controls are supposed to do but of course it doesn't guarantee that this one hasn't been modified and works correctly.

Comment: Why don’t you think 6 is bridge pickup coil split?

Comment: Can you open the back cover, look at the cable connections and draw a diagram? Also, please clarify what is the strange behaviour you mention.

Comment: @ojs: thanks for noticing my mistake: the guitar is actually VS-696 and not VS-635 (don't know how to explain that confusion... lack of coffee maybe). I corrected the post.

Comment: I'll take some time later on to tap on the pickups and open the back cover.

Comment: It's typical that in the middle position, either of the two volume knobs mutes the whole signal, when turned all the way down. Typical guitar wiring is very simple, it's not a mixing console.

Comment: This ad provides some information on the switches: https://reverb.com/item/24808996-vantage-vs-696-matsumoku-made-guitar-early-1980s _The coil tap toggle is "on" when flicked toward the floor, and gives a brighter tone, with some volume reduction.  The "phase" toggle is the second one, and when "on" (flicked toward the floor) provides a notable change in tone:  there's more bite, a bit more of a notched or nasal sound, and a very distinct tone for, say, classic rock blues playing._

Comment: "Phase" may mean several things. A typical setting is inverting the phase of the whole pickup, but that would affect only middle position, which you say is not the case. So another option is changing phase of the individual coils, or perhaps connecting them in parallel?

Comment: The description of "phase" on the reverb listing sounds a lot like two pickups out of phase. I have the feeling that the switch on OP's guitar could be wired to do something different or just not working

Answer (score 1):

Made in the early 1980's at the Matsumoku factory in Japan.

The upper single toggle switch (1) is designed to be the pickup selector switch.
Up = Neck pickup only active.
Middle = Both pickups active.
Down = Bridge pickup active.

2. Neck pickup Volume
3. Bridge pickup volume
4. Master Tone
5. Coil Tap switch.  The coil tap toggle is "on" when flicked toward the floor, and is designed to offer a brighter "Fender like" tone, with some volume reduction.
6. Phase Toggle switch.  Also "on" when flicked toward the floor.
   Designed to reverse the polarity of the pickup(s) signal. This can be used to create a thicker sound, or to cancel out unwanted feedback.

Now.
I say that the controls are "designed to" do the things listed above.
An older guitar frequently builds up corrosion in the circuits and contacts, and things don't always work as advertised.

The solution is (in my experience) to spritz some DeOxit, or other quality electrical contact cleaner into all the pots and movable electronic contact surfaces. Work them around.
You are usually good to go right away.